# How does the return value works in Hashcode override?

Tags: java, collections, overriding, equals, hashcode

In the below code, the overridden method hashCode returns the result. Why are we assigning so many values to result variable before returning it? I got the below code from some tutorials:

```
public class User {
private String name;
private int age;
private String passport;

//getters and setters, constructor

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof User)) {
        return false;
    }

    User user = (User) o;

    return user.name.equals(name) &&
            user.age == age &&
            user.passport.equals(passport);
}

//Idea from effective Java : Item 9
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + age;
    result = 31 * result + passport.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: If you're wondering why it's in a variable that gets modified instead of a single return statement, try writing it both ways and see which is easier to read, write and extend.

Comment: You aren't *really* assigning many values. You are just using the variable as a temporary holder. You could write this as `return 31 * (31 * (31 * 17 + name.hashCode()) + age) + passport.hashCode()`; but it just isn't as clear like that, it's harder to modify etc.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're confused by. The style? The logic? Be more specific. And the attitude is totally unnecessary and unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The successive assignments to `result` are to "scramble" the information contained in it, and to add more information from other sources. Note that `result` is on both sides of the assignment. Starting with a base value of 17, we then do this a few times:

```
result = 31 * result + someValue;
```

By multiplying `result` by 31, we move the existing value to the left a few bits, then add more bits by adding another value to it.

This is a very fast way to come up with a *fairly* unique hash code for every `User` object that you can define.

Comment: People claim that there is no more advantage to using this 17 + 31 * approach to `hashCode()` implementations, and using `Objects.hashCode()` is equivalent since JDK 1.7. Is that a statement that holds past the 21st year of the 21st century?